# Set delete button to hide when all list items have been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to practice some jQuery by creating a todo list. So far I have gotten most of it figured out except hiding the Delete Selected Items button when the list items have been removed.

The process is to create a todo item in the input field and the result shows as an ordered list. The Delete Selected Items button appears when an item has been clicked on in the list and has a strike through. I've tried different ways to remove the button using conditions but that didn't work. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<form id="create-todos">
  <input type="text" name="todo-item" id="todo-item">
  <button id="submit-todo">Add</button>
</form>

<div id="todo-results">
  <ol id="todo-result-list"></ol>
  <button id="delete-striked">Delete Selected Items</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.striked-item {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#delete-striked {
  display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
function submitTodoItem () {
  var todoVal = $('#todo-item').val();
  $('#todo-result-list').append('<li class="result-list-item">' + todoVal + '</li>')
  $('#todo-item').val('');
}

$(function() {
  $('#submit-todo').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitTodoItem(); 
  });
});

function deleteListItem(e, listItem) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(listItem).addClass('striked-item');

  if($(listItem).hasClass('striked-item')) {
    $('#delete-striked').show();
  }
  if($(listItem).length === 0) {
    $('#delete-striked').hide();
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('#todo-result-list').on('click', '.result-list-item', function(e) {
    var listItem = this;
    deleteListItem(e, listItem);
  });
});

function deleteAll() {
  var resultItem = $('.result-list-item');
  resultItem.each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('striked-item')) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#delete-striked').on('click', function() {
    deleteAll();
  });
});

$(function() {
  var listItem = $('#todo-result-list li');
  if($(listItem.length) === 0) {
    $('#delete-striked').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

This is the link to my demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyona/hgp1ghca/).

Comment: Instead of a JSFiddle, create a working snippet right here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Add $('#delete-striked').hide(); to the end of the deleteAll function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hide the delete button.

> $('#delete-striked').hide();

Here's a working solution!

```js
function submitTodoItem () {
  var todoVal = $('#todo-item').val();
  $('#todo-result-list').append('<li class="result-list-item">' + todoVal + '</li>')
  $('#todo-item').val('');
}

$(function() {
  $('#submit-todo').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   submitTodoItem(); 
  });
});

function deleteListItem(e, listItem) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(listItem).addClass('striked-item');
  if($(listItem).hasClass('striked-item')) {
    $('#delete-striked').show();
  }
  if($(listItem).length === 0) {
    $('#delete-striked').hide();
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('#todo-result-list').on('click', '.result-list-item', function(e) {
    var listItem = this;
    deleteListItem(e, listItem);
  });
});

function deleteAll() {
  var resultItem = $('.result-list-item');
  resultItem.each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('striked-item')) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
  $('#delete-striked').hide();
}

$(function() {
  $('#delete-striked').on('click', function() {
    deleteAll();
  });
});

var resultItem = $('#todo-result-list li');
if($(resultItem.length) === 0) {
  $('#delete-striked').fadeOut();
}
```

```css
.striked-item {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#delete-striked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="create-todos">
  <input type="text" name="todo-item" id="todo-item">
  <button id="submit-todo">Add</button>
</form>

<div id="todo-results">
  <ol id="todo-result-list"></ol>
  <button id="delete-striked">Delete Selected Items</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to do this. In my mind I was just thinking to hide the delete button only once but it does make sense to hide the button when all striked through items are deleted since there will be no more strike through items after that. Thanks!

Comment: @Hyona glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try and check that the list is empty when clicked delete button and it has done it's job.

```
$(function() {
  $('#delete-striked').on('click', function() {
    deleteAll();
  if($('.result-list-item').length === 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
  });
});
```

so you can also remove this code snippet that is wrong:

```
if($(listItem).length === 0) {
   $('#delete-striked').hide();
 }
```

this will never happen in your code.

Answer (score 0):

After checking if an element contains any content (*length, .html()*), you can also hide the button by adding a Css class eg. "hidden".

```
$("#delete-striked").addClass("hidden");
```

Removing and adding classes might be useful or easier in some scenarios, if you consider you'd maybe want to add some more todo items items to your list (using *.removeClass()* to remove the 'hidden' class).

Whatever you prefer more, if you go with *.hide()* you can display the button again with *.show()*.

Answer (score 0):

After delete: check if there are any elements with the 'result-list-item' class. 
If not hide the button.

> $('result-list-item').get() returns an array with the matching elements of 'result-list-item'
>
> > if the length of that array is smaller 1 hide the button

```
$(function() 
{
    $('#delete-striked').on('click', function() 
    {
        deleteAll();
        if($('.result-list-item').get().length < 1)
        {
            $('#delete-striked').hide();
        }
    });
});
```